# Как получить данные если тег повторяется несколько раз

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть текст:

```
Тестовое от 05.05.2015 № 2-8-532/2015<br />Тест тест тест<br />Тест тест № 8 ТЕСТ Тест
```

Из него надо вытащить: `№ 2-8-532/2015`

Пишу регулярное выражение:

```
^.*\d\d.\d\d.\d\d\d\d\s(.*)<br />.*
```

Но оно дает: `№ 2-8-532/2015<br />Тест тест тест`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Используй `.*?` вместо `.*`.

И вообще, как-то ты странно достаёшь...

Comment: Вот! Я так понимаю это жадность, т.е. ? означает только первое вхождение?

Comment: @tosick, вопрос означает "возьми как можно меньше". Жадность - это наоборот без него.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно вытащить только часть которая начинается с № и обязательно заканчивается 
 можно как то так

```
(№\s*+[^\<]+)
```

Если не обязателен номер то привязываемся к году

```
\d{4}\s([^\<]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если во всех случаях строка выглядит аналогично вашему примеру, то можно так:

```
/№\s?[-0-9]+\/\d{4}/
```